# Java Stream read & write not working simultaneously

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

Server code-

```
public class ServerPro
{
    ServerSocket server;
    Socket socket;
    BufferedReader read;
    BufferedWriter write;
    String temp;
    ServerPro()
    {

        Thread thread1=new Thread("1st")
         {

           public void run()
           {
               try 
               {
                   do
                 {

                    temp=read.readLine();
                   System.out.println(temp);

                 }while(true);

               }
               catch(Exception e)
               {
                   System.out.print("Line 30 error     :"+e.toString());
               }

           }
         };
         Thread thread2=new Thread("2nd")
                 {
                     public void run()
                     {
                         try 
                           {
                             Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);



                               do
                             {


                                write.write(scan.next());
                                write.newLine();
                                write.flush();


                             }while(true);

                           }
                           catch(Exception e)
                           {
                               System.out.print("Line 53 error     :"+e.toString());
                           }
                     }
                 };
        try
        {

          server=new ServerSocket(5198);
          socket=server.accept();
          System.out.println("Connected ");
          read=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
          write=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));

          thread1.start();
          thread2.start();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Line 72 error     :"+e.toString());
        }

    }
    protected void close() {
        try
        {

            read.close();
            write.close();
            socket.close();
            server.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.print(e.toString());
        }


    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ServerPro obj=new ServerPro();
    }
```

Client code-

```
public class ClientPro
{
    Socket socket;
    BufferedReader read;
    BufferedWriter write;
    String temp;
    ClientPro()
    {
        Thread thread1=new Thread("1st")
         {
            
           public void run()
           {
               try 
               {
                   do
                 {
                    temp=read.readLine();
                    System.out.print(temp);
                 }while(true);
                   close();
               }
               catch(Exception e)
               {
                   System.out.print(e.toString());
               }
            
           }
         };
         Thread thread2=new Thread("2nd")
                 {
                     public void run()
                     {
                         try 
                           {
                             Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
                               do
                             {
                                
                                write.write(scan.nextLine());
                                write.newLine();
                                write.flush();
                                
                             }while(true);
                               close();
                           }
                           catch(Exception e)
                           {
                               System.out.print(e.toString());
                           }
                     }
                 };
        try
        {
          
          socket=new Socket("198.123.45.242",5198);
          read=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
          write=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
          thread1.start();
          thread2.start();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.print(e.toString());
        }

        
    }
    protected void close() {
        try
        {
            read.close();
            write.close();
            socket.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.print(e.toString());
        }
        

    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ClientPro obj=new ClientPro();
    }
}
```

The above code just prints Connected & doesn't work .
In summary both program have two threads invoked to read from stream & write to the stream using BufferedReader & BufferedWriter respectively.
only the write to stream loop is working according to me But read from stream loop is not working at all .

Note- Do while is true for now.But  my intend is keep chatting  till Exit is pressed either by client or server .

Comment: Your client isn't writing anything, it just calls 'write()'?

Comment: @matt sorry , I have edited it .

Comment: You're port numbers are different, but if they weren't correct then you wouldn't get accepted. Did you try sending a net line ending? "\r\n".

Comment: Sorry this program is a part of bigger program & i manually wrote so there are some typos .

Answer (score -1):

I'm changing this answer, what you're doing *should work*. It seems you should just go through a bit more carefully. Here is an example built on your code.

```
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.io.*;

public class ChatSocket{
    Socket socket;
    BufferedReader read;
    BufferedWriter write;
    volatile boolean alive = true;
    public ChatSocket(Socket socket){
        this.socket = socket;
        try{
            read=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            write=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
        } catch(Exception e){
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    public void listen(){
        try{
            while(true){
                String s = read.readLine();
                System.out.println("read: " + s);
                if(s==null){
                    alive = false;
                    return;
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception e){
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } 
    }
    public void write(String s) throws Exception{
            write.write(s);
            write.newLine();
            write.flush();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        ChatSocket cs;
        if("server".equals(args[0])){
            Socket s = new ServerSocket(9993).accept();
            System.out.println("accepted");
            cs = new ChatSocket(s);
            cs.write("Welcome to chat socket");
            new Thread( cs::listen ).start(); 
        } else{
            Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 9993);
            cs = new ChatSocket(s);
            new Thread( cs::listen ).start();
            cs.write("heard yah");
        }
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( System.in ));
        while(cs.alive){
            cs.write(reader.readLine());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @matt ,Please copy paste you code i would running it.

Comment: The problem was the port. He was already sending a line terminator with `newLine()`.

Comment: @user207421 ,Port is not the problem for sure . I wrote above program manually again .So it contains a lot of typos .

Comment: @SiddharthTeli The port was most certainly the problem. You were listening at port 5198 and connecting to port 4363, and failing, and not telling us about the connection reusable. Or else your code didn't compile at all.

Comment: @user207421 trust me ,Port is not the problem both server & client were connecting already but nothing after that .I wrote whole code again because my code is more complex & contains swing program so i did not include it here.By the way i have edited the program & now both connect  & listen at 5198 port no.

Comment: @user207421 I saw that, I was speculating that it could be the difference between the platform line ending, and the standard 'net' line endings. I tried both and realized newLine() worked so I updated my answer.